# Java - Password Field character counter

Tags: java, swing, gettext, jpasswordfield

I have an assignment question that requires me to create a JPasswordField. Two buttons are needed, one to show the actual password in another textfield, and the other just shows the character count in the textfield. Here's what I have to far, but I can't get it to compile because `Method setText in class javax.swing.text.JTextComponent cannot be applied to given types.`
The compiler stops under `bt1` when I want it to read the password itself.

Can anyone help?

Thanks. 
Code:

```
public class JavaPasswordCount {  
    public JavaPasswordCount() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Password Character Count");
        window.setSize(50, 50);
        JButton bt1 = new JButton("Show Count");
        JButton bt2 = new JButton("Show Password");
        final JPasswordField pwd = new JPasswordField();
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField(); 
        final int counter;

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 

        bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tf.setText(pwd.getPassword());
            }
        });

        bt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter = pwd.length();
                tf.setText(counter);
            }
        });

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // Add buttons and TextField to the panel
        panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(pwd);
        panel.add(bt1);
        panel.add(bt2);

        window.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        JavaPasswordCount application = new JavaPasswordCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this lines:

```
counter = pwd.length();
tf.setText(counter);
```

to

```
int counter = pwd.getPassword().length;
tf.setText(String.valueOf((counter)));
```

and this

```
tf.setText(pwd.getPassword());
```

To

```
tf.setText(pwd.getPassword().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks @MrD. But I still get the same error - it stops at the portion under "bt1" when I want it to read the actual password.

Comment: No problem mate. Remember to check it :)